# How did a zombie get onto the plane in World War Z?

Tags: plot-explanation, world-war-z

In [*World War Z* (2013)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0816711/) it is established that it takes a person around a minute to turn into a zombie once bitten. The scene where Brad Pitt chops off the hand of the lady lieutenant and waits for a while to see if she turns, and when she doesn't, he's sure she can't become a zombie establishes the timing.

In the scene where an air-hostess opens the washroom door in the plane and gets bitten by a zombie locked in the washroom, I was wondering how that scene even added up.

The guy should have turned to zombie at the airport, in the lines or while boarding or by the time he got onto the plane because it takes a very very short span of time to turn. He couldn't possibly have turned on the plane since he would need someone on the plane to infect him, but he was the only zombie on the plane!

**How did this zombie end up on the plane?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here at 0:23 you can see that the zombie comes out from a kind of elevator (not a washroom), so it probably was stuck in a lower level of the plane, and was freed when the hostess called the elevator.

Answer (score 2):

WWZ how the zombie got on the plane? If you watch carefully when the plane takes off (sequence 1.09.43), the door of the baggage compartment opens. There is the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I always assumed that the zombie got inside the fuselage during takeoff, as there's a shot of zombies dragged by the raising back wheels.

Some A310-300 seat plans seem to show some sort of cabin/space that could fit an elevator next to the tail exits and  right before the bathrooms, which matches the movie separations, including the business class courtains.

This one has an additional separation for first class but maybe our movie's Belarus Airline's was just Business and Economy.

https://www.stratosjets.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Airbus-A310-300.svg